# Adding Custom Link anchors in the top menu that points to specific sections of the site home page

Tags: customization, menus, urls

My site is using a nav menu in my custom theme. I want to add navigation links to anchored links that points to specific sections of the site home page using a `Custom Link` in the nav menu.

I want to use the equivalent of:

```
<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/#xxxx
```

in the URL field. If I use just the anchored link `#xxx` as the `Custom Link`, it will work fine on the home page, but it will not link from another page (as that anchor section is not on that page).

There has to be a clean way to do this. When I insert the php code as well, it appears to work on the home page, but not from another page. I've gone through all the other related posts, but none seem to address this issue.

Comment: Can't you just put the full URL of the site into the custom link, with the anchor?

Comment: see my comment below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is to go to a specific section of the home page, then the easiest way is to use the **relative URL** mark `/` and then use the anchor `#xxx`.

So the custom link for the menu will be: `/#xxx`.

> **Note the difference between `#xxx` and `/#xxx`** as custom link.

The best thing about this approach is that you'll not have to bother changing the link after you go live, and additionally, this needs no programming.

Comment: This will only work on the home page. If you are on the About Us page it will not jump to the home page anchor.

Comment: @user1572121: If you put custom link as `#xxx` then it'll not work on say the About Page, however, **if you add the slash (`/`) before the anchor**, like `/#xxx` then it'll work everywhere.  Because after adding the slash at the beginning, it effectively becomes the home page.

Comment: OK, added the slash and it appears to work as intended. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can add the `/index.php/#my-anchor` in your custom links, try it.

Or, you can just put your intire URL in your links.

Comment: It doesn't like the /index.php/#anchor path. I want to avoid using the site's full url since it's currently running on my localhost and a demo install. Using the ``echo get_home_url`` works on a hard coded menu, but not so much on this custom menu.

Comment: You’re probably going to need to do a search replace on the URL when going live anyway.